# How to disable implicit string trimming in doctrine2 entity for string max length?

Tags: php, mysql, string, doctrine-orm, maxlength

Using dontrine2, I have an entity having property with following annotations:

```
/**
 * @var string
 * @Column(type="string", length=4, nullable=false)
 */
protected $someProperty;
```

Now when the property is set to `foobar`, instead of getting an exception the string is trimmed to its first four characters, i.e. `foob` which is then stored into the database.

I know that I could implement a length check in the setter. Yet then I would configure the length of the string in two places which I rather avoid.

I also could use a validation, yet this also would double the configuration.

I find it confusing that doctrine2 shortens the string implicitly, yet when setting the value to `null` when nullable is false, I get an exception. This seems inconsistent.

Can I disable the trimming and force an exception? Or do I have to validate the entity myself?

Comment: I think Doctrine does not shorten a string. It happens on database level.

Comment: @kormik It is a mysql database and it would be great to disable that feature if possible.

Comment: Have a look on MySql STRICT mode. If you enable it it should raise an error instead of truncating data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doctrine does not do any validation neither any string truncation. All exceptions you get comes from database layer.

When you try to insert null value into a column which is not allowed to be null database query fails.

When you try to insert a string value longer than length defined in a column   definition MySql automatically truncate it. You can change this behaviour configuring MySql to use STRICT mode.